# Discrepancy between docbook.dtd and docbook.rng on the DocBook 5.0 Distribution

Tags: xml, dtd, relaxng, docbook-5

When I validate my document using RelaxNG and the `docbook.rng` schema provided on the DocBook 5.0 distribution, errors like this crop up,

```
error: attribute "title" not allowed at this point; ignored
```

and the offending XML element is `informaltable`. In fact, I read on the O'Reilly site that the basic definition of an `informaltable` is a table without a title. However, the `docbook.dtd` DTD, that is provided on that same distribution, specified the `title` as an attribute on an `informatltable`. So is this an error in the DTD?

DTD snippet, included here, for reference. If this DTD is indeed incorrect, is there a correct one around somewhere, or can I generate it somehow?

```
<!ELEMENT informaltable (info?, ((textobject*, (mediaobject+|tgroup+))|((col*|colgroup*), thead?, tfoot?, (tbody+|tr+))))>

<!ATTLIST informaltable
    xmlns   CDATA   #FIXED  "http://docbook.org/ns/docbook"
    role    CDATA   #IMPLIED
    %db.common.attributes;
    %db.common.linking.attributes;
    tabstyle    CDATA   #IMPLIED
    floatstyle  CDATA   #IMPLIED
    orient  (land|port) #IMPLIED
    colsep  (0|1)   #IMPLIED
    rowsep  (0|1)   #IMPLIED
    frame   (all|bottom|none|sides|top|topbot|void|above|below|hsides|lhs|rhs|vsides|box|border)    #IMPLIED
    pgwide  (0|1)   #IMPLIED
    rowheader   (firstcol|norowheader)  #IMPLIED
    class   CDATA   #IMPLIED
    style   CDATA   #IMPLIED
    title   CDATA   #IMPLIED
    lang    CDATA   #IMPLIED
    onclick CDATA   #IMPLIED
    ondblclick  CDATA   #IMPLIED
    onmousedown CDATA   #IMPLIED
    onmouseup   CDATA   #IMPLIED
    onmouseover CDATA   #IMPLIED
    onmousemove CDATA   #IMPLIED
    onmouseout  CDATA   #IMPLIED
    onkeypress  CDATA   #IMPLIED
    onkeydown   CDATA   #IMPLIED
    onkeyup CDATA   #IMPLIED
    summary CDATA   #IMPLIED
    width   CDATA   #IMPLIED
    border  NMTOKEN #IMPLIED
    rules   (none|groups|rows|cols|all) #IMPLIED
    cellspacing CDATA   #IMPLIED
    cellpadding CDATA   #IMPLIED

>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DocBok 5.0 DTD is only an approximation. A document that validates against the DTD is not necessarily valid against the normative RELAX NG schema.

DocBook supports two types of table structures, CALS and HTML. The `title` attribute on `informaltable` is only supported in HTML tables. The RELAX NG schema can distinguish between these two types of tables (with the same name), but in a DTD it is not possible to enforce the restriction that `title` is allowed only in HTML tables.

See also https://docbook.org/docs/howto/howto.html#introduction-schemas.